# RactiveJS iterator with on-click behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, templating, ractivejs

I am attempting to fire a function that is part of the data object I'm passing to RactiveJS when populating a template. I've tried a few other libraries, but I can't find what I'm looking for. Here is the description of what I'm doing, and I'm hopeful that someone can suggest a library for doing what I'm trying to do.

A service is feeding my application a JSON Object that looks something like this

```
var data = {
    "users": {
        "Aaron": {
            "age": "31",
            "level": "legit",
            "talk": function(){
                console.log("Howdy! I'm " + this.level);
            }
        },
        "Pete": {
            "age": "30",
            "level": "godlike",
            "talk": function(){
                console.log("Howdy! I'm " + this.level);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

My template appears to be correct As instructed by the [Documentation](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/mustaches#object-iteration)

```
var usersTemplate = "<ul>{{#users:name}}<li><a href='#' on-click='talk'>{{name}} says:</li>{{/users}}</ul>";
```

Then I build a new Ractive instance

```
var people = new Ractive({
    el: "#userlist",
    template: usersTemplate ,
    data: data
});
```

Trouble is, clicking on each user won't actually do anything because RactiveJS doesn't seem to work like that. It handles events like [this](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/events#proxy-events).

```
people.on({
    talk: function(evt){
        evt.original.preventDefault();
        console.log("I clicked on the template");
    }
});
```

What I'm trying to do is trigger the `action` function inside of the data object that I passed in without the controller knowing what the name of the method is. Specifying it in the template, and in the data object should be enough.

Ractive gives enough information that I can traverse the data object, but this isn't good enough.

```
people.on({
    talk: function( evt ) {
        evt.original.preventDefault();
        var pointer = json_output;
        var path = evt.keypath.split(".");
        for( var i = 0; i < path.length; i++){
            console.log(i);
            pointer = pointer[path[i]];
        }
        if(pointer.hasOwnProperty("action") && typeof(pointer.action) === "function") {
            pointer.action(evt);
        }
    }
});
```

[JSBin Example](http://jsbin.com/pijop/2/edit)

Is RactiveJS not the right library for the job? Thank you ahead of time for helping me in my search.

Comment: did you see `proxy events` part of docs? is `event.context` what you are asking about?

Comment: Hi vittore. Thanks for taking a look at my question. To answer your question, Yes. I did see the documentation about proxy events. The problem with that is that I want each button to do a different thing, and I might not know ahead of time what the name of the event is.

Comment: Can you expand that in the question, because for what I see now my answer seems to be enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While Ractive doesn't allow you to call functions directly, it supports event arguments, so there's a very nice workaround for this:

```html
<a on-click="call:talk">Talk</a>
```

```js
var ractive = new Ractive({
    el: "#userlist",
    template: usersTemplate,
    data: data
});

ractive.on('call', function ( event, method ) {
    event.context[method]();
});
```

Comment: This is a great solution. It needs a small tweak to work for this example though - because the function references `this`, it needs to be called as a method: http://jsfiddle.net/rich_harris/N5a2Y/. Otherwise it logs 'Howdy! I'm undefined' http://jsfiddle.net/rich_harris/Xf5pm/1/

Comment: Sweet. Thanks. This will work. @RichHarris, In the interest of knowing why Ractive doesn't support calling functions directly, where does the on-click directive get removed during parsing?

Comment: @Cmndo It's not so much that the on-click directive gets removed, as that it never gets 'added' - directives (on-click, intro, decorator, etc) are part of the virtual DOM but are never rendered to the real DOM - it's completely different to the old-school `onclick` attribute. There's a [relevant GitHub discussion about calling functions directly](https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/issues/568#issuecomment-47437324), though it refers to calling *component* methods rather than functions inside the data object.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your code like this:

```
 people.on({
     talk: function( evt ) {
         evt.original.preventDefault();
         evt.context.talk(evt)
     }
 });
```

moreover, you can think about more `meta` way of doing that:

```
 function getProxyHandler(eventName) {
    return function(event) {
       event.context[eventName](event)
    }
 }
```

this way your events might be assigned like:

```
 people.on({ 
     talk:getProxyHandler('talk'), 
     eat: getProxyHandler('eat') 
 })
```

Using custom events the @Martin showed you can change the handler to apply or call function within event like this:

```
 people.on('call' , function(event, method) {
      method.call(event.context)
 })
```

Comment: I greatly appreciate your help on narrowing the search. With what I'm doing, it would be a tremendous help if the object that stores the events that are passed to `people.on` creates itself from the methods specified in the template.

Comment: @Cmndo I added example of what can be done in order to solve your issue with Martin's solution.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm having a look at this.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way to automate the creation of the object you pass to `people.on()` given the value of the template's on-click attributes? Ractive removes these on-click attributes

Otherswise, something like this could be hacked together with jQuery

```
var people = new Ractive({
    el: "#userlist",
    template: usersTemplate,
    data: data,
    complete: function(){
        var onHandler = {}, action;

        $("[on-click]", "#userlist").each(function(e){

            action = $(this).attr('on-click');
            onHanlder[action] = getProxyHandler(action);

       });

    this.on(onHandler);
  }
});
```